# What happens to Attributes when a .Net method is inlined?

Tags: .net, inline

I have some code inside a class that is crawling the stack trace to look for a specific attribute on a method in its call stack.

I noticed that one of my tests started failing from the automated build, when that test always passed from my machine.  When I dug into it, it appeared that the code in question worked fine in either debug mode or in release mode so long as you had a debugger attached, but failed in release mode with no debugger.

From what I can see, the method that I'm looking for is getting inlined, and when that happens the Attributes on that method are lost.

Is that the case?  Are the attributes lost at that point?

Here is a small app that reproduces my issue:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;


namespace InliningAndAttributes
{

    public class SomeClass
    {

        [Description("Foo")]
        public void SomeMethodThatWillGetInlined()
        {
            SomeMethodThatWontGetInlined();
        }

        protected virtual void SomeMethodThatWontGetInlined()
        {
            var caller = FindDescribedCaller();
            Console.WriteLine("Could I find description attribute? {0}", caller != null);
        }

        private MethodBase FindDescribedCaller()
        {
            var callStack = new StackTrace();
            int frameIndex = 0;
            while (frameIndex++ <= callStack.FrameCount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting frame" + frameIndex);
                var currentFrame = callStack.GetFrame(frameIndex);
                if (currentFrame == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var method = currentFrame.GetMethod();
                Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
                if (Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)))
                {
                    return method;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someClass = new SomeClass();
            someClass.SomeMethodThatWillGetInlined();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this application under .Net 4.5, with a Release build and without the debugger attached I get the following output:

```
Getting frame1
SomeMethodThatWontGetInlined
Getting frame2
Main
Getting frame3
Getting frame4
Could I find description attribute? False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User code cannot detect inlining. If it could this would be a broken compiler optimization. Optimizations are undetectable (except if they exploit undefined or unspecified behavior, of course).

The bug is not that attributes are lost. The bug is that your code depends on a runtime `StackTrace` which indeed has unspecified contents. This is a debugging class providing best-effort data. Inlining removes stack frames.

You should probably not depend on the caller of your method. (Not just because it doesn't work but also because it is very brittle and not self-documenting). Find a different solution. Make the caller identify itself by passing an additional argument.